# macports memcached restart Mac OS X

Tags: php, memcached

I installed memcached using mac ports:

http://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2012/02/18/installing-memcached-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard/

I am able to start memcache but I cannot figure out how to restart it.

I started it by doing:
memcached -d

Comment: failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Address already in use

Comment: That error is because its already running, would kill it `killall memcached` and then start it back up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo launchctl unload  /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.memcached/org.macports.memcached.plist

sudo launchctl load    /opt/local/etc/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.memcached/org.macports.memcached.plist

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo port unload memcached
sudo port load memcached
```

Comment: an explanation of how/why this solves the problem would improve the long-term value of this post.